# How to submit and fetch an IP adress from URL?

Tags: php, url, ip

I'd like to enter

```
example.com/192.168.1.1
example.com/192.168.2.1:80
example.com/anotherexample.net
example.com/yetanotheraxample.org:20
```

in the browsers adress bar.

How do I fetch the IP adresses and ports from that, without getting 404 and 403 errors shown?

Comment: mod rewrite in .htacess

Comment: or example.com/?q=192.168.1.1

Comment: would like to get rid of these extra characters

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work for you.
Put this into your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And in your index.php file you can get passed string like this:

```
$passedStr = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
echo $passedStr;
```

Result:
After entering something like this in URL (example.com/192.168.1.1), variable $passedStr will contain string "192.168.1.1"

Comment: Thank you, it is working with `/example.com` and `/127.0.0.1` however if I add a port after, 403 will laugh at me. The colon will cause this, no matter whats after. Is there a way to fetch ANY string this way?

Comment: Well: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual_talk%3aShort_URL/Archive_1#Colon_issue_with_Very_Short_URLs_on_Windows

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. Loot at my test script:
http://roob.lv/test/192.168.2.1:80
and there only my mentioned .htaccess and one php file

Comment: Are you running a linux webserver? Im currently developing on win/xampp

Comment: Yes, it is linux server.